# CSS padding in percent

Tags: css, padding, percentage

I just noticed something really weird, have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a98tJ/1/). There are two containers with different heights. Both containers' elements are set to vertical padding of 10%, which would logically mean that the shorter container's elements should be closer to one another. Surprisingly that's not the case. Could someone explain this behavior to me, I would like to know whether it is safe to say that a padding in percentage would be constant in value ( px ) regardless of the parent's height?

### HTML:

```
<div class='foo'>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
</div>
<div class='bar'>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.foo, .bar { display:inline-block; border:solid black 1px; }

.foo { height: 200px; }
.foo > div { padding-top: 10%; }

.bar { height:300px; }
.bar > div { padding-top: 10%; }
```

Comment: "This is some code, because SO will not allow me to post the question.." - why not post the relevant code from the fiddle into the question? The code requirement is there for a reason.

Comment: @MikeK I agree, will edit

Comment: But anyhoo, the 10% is in relation to the size of the text's `div`, not the parent containers `div`. Since the text between both `div`s are the same, they will have the same amount of padding.

Comment: @MikeK Why post the answer as a comment?

Comment: By your question, it sounds like you want to have the one div's text closer together. However, I don't have an answer to that part. Additionally I personally don't believe the comment I provided has enough quality to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @MikeK I thought padding percentages worked like height and width percentages, depending on the parent's height/width. If percentages in padding depend on the element's size itself, instead of the parent's, then this answers the question solidly.

Comment: Then you now have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

padding in percentages based on width, since your width is the same they will be the same.  Try adding a width equal to the height like this:

```
.foo, .bar { display:inline-block; border:solid black 1px; }

.foo { height: 200px; width: 200px; }
.foo div { padding-top: 10%; }

.bar { height:300px; width: 300px; }
.bar div { padding-top: 10%; }
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a98tJ/8/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The 10% is in relation to the size of the text's `div`, not the parent containers `div`. Since the text between both `div`s are the same, they will have the same amount of padding.